# In Java 8, What data moved to Java heap space?

Tags: java, jvm

I saw [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-8-permgen-metaspace) article about a days ago.

In middle of this article.

> Some miscellaneous data has been moved to the Java heap space. This means you may observe an increase of the Java heap space following a future JDK 8 upgrade.

This quote brings me some question. Exactly what data moved to Java heap space In new Jdk8.

sorry for my poor enligsh.

Answer (score 3):

http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/122

From "Remove the Permanent Generation":

> The proposed implementation will allocate class meta-data in native memory and move **interned Strings and class statics to the Java heap**